# Backbone App -> PHP/Slim/CorsSlim API: PUT Getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: php, backbone.js, cors, slim

Update 6 July: Thanks to @gettleto I've managed to find the `response` header options and OPTIONS route that works without errors, but I kind of hacked my way around and frankly don't understand which `response` headers should be listed, what might be missing, if any are extraneous  or if the API is vulnerable.

If there is a 'best practices' or a guide anyone can refer me to, that would be terrific. I've spent a few hours trying to find a guide for the uninitiated, but no love.

Update 27 June: I discovered that Backbone sends a preflight request to the server before the POST, which led me to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005829/cors-post-request-fails). I added the OPTIONS route to the API (see code below), and get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://foxworkx.dev/bookAPI.php/books. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' is therefore not allowed access.` in the console, BUT the API allowed the POST to work!?

Both the OPTIONS and POST requests are getting a status:200 OK.

So, It seems odd that I set CorsOptions and add to $app, but need an OPTIONS route with defined response headers.

Any help appreciated.
/Update 27 June

I am working thru a Backbone tutorial, and built a simple MySQL/PHP API using Slim3 and CorsSlim3. The GET is working with no errors. The weird part is the POST is INSERTing into MySQL, so I'm thinking it's a callback issue, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

My PHP API code

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

// CORS
$corsOptions = array(
    "origin" => array( "http://127.0.0.1:8081" ),

    "allowMethods" => array('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'),
    "exposeHeaders" => array( "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Origin", "Authorization" ),
    "allowHeaders" => array( "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Origin", "Authorization" )
);
$cors = new \CorsSlim\CorsSlim( $corsOptions );
$app->add( $cors );
// END CORS

/* 
ROUTES 
*/
// GET all
$app->get( '/books', function ( Request $request, Response $response ) {
    $sql = "select * FROM bookDB ORDER BY title";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $books = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($books);
    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
} );
// OPTIONS ( preflighted requests )------NEW
$app->options( '/books',
    function( Request $request, Response $response, $args ) {
        return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8081')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
);
// ADD one 
$app->post('/books', function ( Request $request, Response $response ) {
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();
    $book = [];
    $book[ 'title' ] = filter_var( $data[ 'title' ] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $book[ 'author' ] = filter_var( $data[ 'author' ] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $book[ 'releaseDate' ] = filter_var( $data[ 'releaseDate' ] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $book[ 'keywords' ] = filter_var( $data[ 'keywords' ] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    $sql = "INSERT INTO bookDB ( title,author,releaseDate,keywords ) VALUES ( '" . $book[ 'title' ]  . "', '" . $book[ 'author' ]  . "', '" . $book[ 'releaseDate' ] . "', '" . $book[ 'keywords' ] . "' )";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->execute();
    //  $book[ 'id' ] = $db->lastInsertId();
    //  error_log("book id:", $book[ 'id' ] );
        $db = null;
    //  echo json_encode($book ); 



    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        error_log( $e->getMessage() );
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }

    // return $response
    //  ->withJson($book)
    //  ->withJson( array( error => array( "text" => $e->getMessage() ) ) );



} );
```

And my Backbone.view

```
        var app = app || {};

app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click #add' : 'addBook'
    },

    el: '#books',

    initialize: function() {

        this.collection = new app.Library();
        this.collection.fetch( { reset:true } );
        this.render();

        this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
        this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );
    },

    // render library by rendering each book in its collection
    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function( item ) {
            this.renderBook( item );
        }, 
        this );
    },

    // render a book by creating a BookView and appending the
    // element it renders to the library's element
    renderBook: function( item ) {
        var bookView = new app.BookView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append( bookView.render().el );
    },

    addBook: function( e ) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = {};

        $( '#addBook div' ).children( 'input' ).each( function( i, el ) {
            if( $( el ).val() != '' ) {
                formData[ el.id ] = $( el ).val();
            }
            // Clear input field value
                $( el ).val('');
        } );
        // add to this.collection AND POST the data
        this.collection.create( formData );

    }

});
```

And my PHP error_log:

```
[24-Jun-2016 09:59:15 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
[24-Jun-2016 09:59:15 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you retry this with returning the response objects from your route actions...

```
return $response->withJson($book);
return $response->withJson(array(error => array("text" => $e->getMessage())));
```

It would be helpful if you added more of your bootstrapping code on the Server side...

**Edit**
You need the headers on both requests [options and actual resource]

Comment: @gettleto: I'm not getting anything back using this code.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. You need to attach the OPTIONS headers to both the OPTIONS Request and the actual resource!

Comment: Yes, but I thought `$cors = new \CorsSlim\CorsSlim( $corsOptions ); $app->add( $cors );` was attaching it to the $app instance. No?

Comment: hmm... yes it should be adding the cors middleware to the entire app... I am not very familar with CorsSlim, I'm just a Slim core developer...

Comment: Check out this thread, someone had a similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005829/cors-post-request-fails/38035128#38035128