# CorsSlim config for prevent No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, slim

I am new in PHP Slim Framwork. I am build an Rest API base on https://github.com/moritz-h/slim3-rest-skeleton and
I have an error like this

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access "Slim"

And I fix it by using https://github.com/palanik/CorsSlim library with configure below

```
$settings = require __DIR__.'/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);
$corsOptions = array(
    "origin" => "*",
    "exposeHeaders" => array("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "X-authentication", "X-client"),
    "allowMethods" => array('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS')
);
$cors = new \CorsSlim\CorsSlim($corsOptions);
$app->add($cors);
require __DIR__.'/dependencies.php';
require __DIR__.'/../app/routes.php';
```

It seem like I found the right library for fix it but the error still happened. Do I miss something with Slim? Any help or suggestion would be great aprreciated.

Comment: im not into slim php but as a personal experience using the generic way of handling CORS in php i found that "origin: *" do not work as expected so can tou try set origin to $_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]  and see if that works

Comment: @Strife86 I have tried it but it say Undefined index: HTTP_ORIGIN

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005829/cors-post-request-fails/38035128#38035128

Comment: @geggleto I also tried your solution but it still not work, in your answer you 1/2 the solution, can you help me full solution. I'm stuck at this for a long time :((( please help

Comment: then try this "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: @PhanVanLinh the original question holder had the other 1/2 of the solution1