# CORS Failing for post request

Tags: cors, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I have this piece of Vue.js:

```
...
this.$http.post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', postData)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
})
this.$http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/test')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
})
...
```

The last get request works fine, but the post doesn't go through due to

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/oauth/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ...

My Cors.php Middleware:

```
...
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
...
```

Kernel.php:

```
...

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ],
...
```

I've done `php artisan route:list` I noticed that the route `...oauth/token` has the middleware `throttle`, it is the only one by default ... I'm following https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#installation

Both (client/server) are running on localhost

Comment: Try to register the middleware into the web middleware group instead of the api one

Comment: @El_Matella, then the two requests fail. I did a `php artisan route:list` and that route only middleware is `throttle`

Comment: And if you register it globally?

Comment: If i registered on `protected $middleware` the problem in the question remains

Comment: Does it work if you add: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');`

Comment: Problem remains :/ , Doens't make any sense ... Why just for post?! @craig_h

Comment: Does this post help at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005829/cors-post-request-fails

Comment: Do you need CORS because you're developing front end with a server run by node.js? If so, you can try configuring it proxy the back end to avoid CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using *vue-resource* try debugging your call in the Network tab from *devtools*.

If no CORS headers are present in *Request Header* tab put this line somewhere after the `Vue.use(VueResource)` : `Vue.http.options.crossOrigin = true`